# change PrimaryKey when using json data in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm making an Ember.js app that get posts from a xml file and converts it to json with xml2json. Ember expects an "id" in the json file but there isn't one and I would like to change that to "title" instead.

Here is my code.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var url = "/rss.xml";
    return Ember.$.get(url).then(function (xml) {
      var json = $.xml2json(xml);
        return json.channel.item.map(function(article) {
          article.body = article.description;
          return article;
        });
    });
  }
});
```

There are some old answers, but they don't seem to work anymore.
I'm running ember-1.5.1.js.

I can't figure out what should be in `App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({`
And how to change "id" to "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your resource slug to title.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:title' });
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    /// $.get('/url' + params.title);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. didn't think it was that easy with the resource slug.

I'm still having trouble with the PostRoute.

I can't figure out where to put the "+ params.title" when I'm getting my json file through xml2json. I'm thinking that I need the code from the PostsRoute but I don't know what to change.

Comment: You'll need to implement some sort of call to the server in the post route, unless you plan on making the post resource a child of the posts resource.  If you were to do this, you could just grab that particular post from the posts resource's collection.  Currently as it stands you could hit the posts resource or post resource without hitting the other, which means you'd need to implement making a call to your server for the requested data in both route's model hook.